# Android WebView showing granulation backgroun - Only with text which is shorter than 1 row

Tags: android, android-webview

Hi i found some issue of WebView in Android. I use WebView for justifying text which i want to show user. But when i show text shorter than 2rows it sometimes looks like this:

Link:http://tinypic.com/r/1z4btav/5
- i have not required reputation to post images

Class of this WebView:

```
    public class BlockJustifyTextView extends WebView {

private final String TAG = "BlockJustifyTextView";


public BlockJustifyTextView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    Log.d(TAG, TAG + " constructor1");
}

public BlockJustifyTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    Log.d(TAG, TAG + " constructor2");
}

public BlockJustifyTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    Log.d(TAG, TAG + " constructor3");
}

public void setText(String text) {
    Log.d(TAG, "TouristGuideTag - setText");

    //float density = getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().scaledDensity;
    //int textSize = (int) ((24 * (1/density)) + 0.5);
    String color = "181,181,181,255";

    String html = "<html><body style='text-align:justify; color:rgba(%s);background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.0);'>%s</body></html>";
    setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    loadData(String.format(html, color, text), "text/html; charset=UTF-8", null);
    this.getSettings().setTextSize(WebSettings.TextSize.NORMAL);
}
```

}

Sorry for my bad english. I will work on that.